# Why was this question closed?

Tags: discussion, support

There is no explanation as to [why my question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278175/do-any-open-source-linux-terminals-and-fonts-support-ligatures?noredirect=1#comment483761_278175) is closed. I'd like it reopened as it seems to be on topic.

It's asking about the support of native Linux terminals.

Answer (score 3):

Well, technically, there is an explanation:

> This question does not appear to be about Unix or Linux within the scope defined in the help center.

Your first version (before your edit) was borderline, in my opinion, but was validly closed. The edit was an improvement; when I encountered it in the Reopen review queue, however, I voted to keep closed. Looking back on it, I probably should have gone the other way.

A listing of the terminals and fonts in Linux that support ligatures seems a worthwhile enough resource to have here.

Comment: I don't see how the question was ever about anything other than ligatures and terminals that support them, I'd highly urge the admins that voted to close it to be more open to reforming questions rather than closing them.

Comment: @EvanCarroll Your first version was closeworthy. Also, admins didn't close it: it takes five votes from users with mid-level reputation to do it.

Comment: @EvanCarroll I don't appear to have voted on your question but I'm pretty sure I'd have gone with "unclear". I still don't understand what it is that you were asking there, and I'm perplexed as to the relevance of a GIF with animated text appearing in red and black. For example, why should it be useful for a terminal font to "render `==` as a single character"?

Comment: @roaima you don't have to agree with what I want to understand fully what I want -- which is clear in your question. This isn't about you criticizing my preference, it's about my question.

Comment: In math, we don't draw `=` + ` ` + `=`. I'd like that to reflect in my rendering in the terminal. It was important enough for unicode to adopt it, and fonts to implement it then it should be a valid question here. The gif is relevant because it shows the terminal taking two discrete unicode inputs and rendering that as a ligature. Otherwise you wouldn't know if `==` was a ligature, potentially two characters, or one complex [unicode Relational Equality grapheme ⩵](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_operator#Equality) Showing it as you're typing illustrates that.

Comment: @EvanCarroll if I don't understand enough of what the question is asking I can't work out whether it's in my domain or not. From this conversation here it's clear that it's not in my area of expertise so I would skip the question entirely, but in the original question it is not clear (to me) at all what it's asking.

Comment: You nailed it. Press '=' on your keyboard. Press it again. I want that to render a complex font-mapped ligature that looks discrete from two `=` back to back. Now press Backspace. I want that complex ligature to go away and one `=` to be remaining. Press it again. I want it to come back. That's how ligature rendering is supposed to work for [all these ligatures](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tonsky/FiraCode/master/showcases/all_ligatures.png). I want to know what terminals and open source fonts support that.

Comment: @EvanCarroll beautifully described. Thank you.